# Can someone point out why these lines of code for authentication don't work?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, authentication

Not sure what's wrong.  I've tried removing the space between the < and % but the app wouldn't run.

```
< % if logged_in? %>  
  Welcome < %= current_user.username %>! Not you?  
  < %= link_to "Log out", logout_path %>  
< % else %>  
  < %= link_to "Sign up", signup_path %> or  
  < %= link_to "log in", login_path %>.  
< % end %>
```

The error I get is:

```
NoMethodError in Posts#index undefined method `logged_in?' for #<#<Class:0x00000101ab0250>:0x00000101aab0c0>
```

[image]

Comment: We need more infos, what happens? do you get an error message? <% should run just fine.

Comment: Hi tony! What doesn't work about it? Do you get an error message?

Comment: This is what I get:

NoMethodError in Posts#index

undefined method `logged_in?' for #<#<Class:0x00000101ab0250>:0x00000101aab0c0>

Comment: What authentication plugin are you using?

Comment: I'm using the nifty-generators gem.

Comment: you're most probably missing some require so the `logged_in` method can be found. Check where it is located and see if it can be found from where you try to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean :

```
 <% if current_user.logged_in? %>
```

Your current piece of code will try to use the logged_in? helper wich i guess is not what you want.

Comment: Nope, that's not it.  My app doesn't look when I use <%.  But I appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you paste the definition of logged_in? method ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the "restful_authentication", trying adding `include AuthenticatedSystem` like below

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time
  include AuthenticatedSystem
  .....
```

`logged_in?` is a protected method inside the AuthenticatedSystem module

```
module AuthenticatedSystem
  protected
    # Returns true or false if the <%= file_name %> is logged in.
    # Preloads @current_<%= file_name %> with the <%= file_name %> model if they're logged in.
    def logged_in?
      !!current_<%= file_name %>
    end
    ......
```

HTH